# Object Oriented Design to Sudoku puzzle

Tags: oop

I'm tring to design a Sudoku puzzle in OOD.

On the one hand it seems cheap to represent to board in a matrix with a validation function that will be activate after each insertions

On the other hand it may be more convenient to represent the board with "blocks":
each cell will be assigned with the three blocks containing it - column, row, square.
The validation function here will be implement differently according to the block class (col/row/square) using polymorphism and when you insert the number is activated 3 times on each block belonging to the cell.
This way seems more "OOD" but it is very expensive from the memory aspect.

Which way do you think is better? 
Is there better way that is OOD but still cheap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make a more generic sudoku solver (there are other forms), you could use:

**Cell**

- Has a position on the screen
- Can contain a symbol belonging to a limited alphabet or be empty.
- Belongs to one or more groups.
- Some cells have a fixed value (they can't be changed).
- Each time a cell is about to be changed, the new value must be valid in all groups.

**Generic Group**

- Contains a number of cells, not exceeding the number of symbols in the alphabet.
- A generic group has a IsValid method.

**Normal Sudoku Group**

- The IsValid method returns true if all non empty cells contain different values.

**Other Sodoku Group**

- (You can define your own IsValid function).

**Note** It could even be possible to mix different group types.

Comment: Note that the groups in killer sudoku _can_ contain repeated values. You might want to introduce a separate concept of an exclusion group (which rows, columns and blocks would be)

Comment: Thanks @Toon Krijthe for the advice of how to do it more generic. What about the two aspects I mentioned? Object-oriented design compared with memory allocation? which is more important here?

Comment: The primary focus should be a good design. If resources or performance is a problem, you can always improve that later. But with Sudoku solvers, the amount of memory needed is minimal so don't expect any problems.

Comment: @user1961083 that depends on the target environment. A single object is cheap, but one million un-GC-able objects could be quite expensive. One hundred objects could be a problem if you're targetting an embedded device with 4kB of memory. A desktop machine won't mind.

Comment: Note that a "sudoku solver" could refer to a hand-held baterry-powered device with a black&white LCD screen and just five membrane buttons.

Comment: @Toon Krijthe So if they ask me such a question in an interview - I should give the more "complex" design to meet the generic needs, but mention that if there is a need of millions boards - then the representation should be more basic?

Comment: Unfortunately, it depends.  Some interviewers chose design before optimizing and others focus on optimizing first.  So follow your common sense.

Comment: @Toon Krijthe Thank you very much for the advice. And for mention in the different details may affect the design (like the 5 buttons - wouldn't think on that..)!

Comment: I feel that Groups should be subclassed into Horizontal Group,Vertical Group,Square Group. Each of this group must have isValid Method.